# Phyton или Java

Tags: java, python

Мне сейчас 11 лет и у меня задача - к 14 знать 2-3 яп (сам себе такую задачу поставил)

Я сейчас уже достаточно хорошо владею JS (на изучение ушло 1.5 мес. )(html и css в список входит). Но на одном JS далеко не уедешь...

Сейчас я выбираю, что первым учить - python или java (всё равно их потом выучу оба). Пока предпочтение к питону, нуууу, я не уверен. А куда вы мне посоветуете идти?

p.s. Обо мне:

**Люблю:** кроссплатформенные яп, опп, web-development, android, notepad++, open sourse (и чужой и свой), привлекать друзей к разработке, самообучение яп, логические задачки да и математику в целом, обожаю синтаксис JS

**Не люблю:** pascal, среды разработки (но не средства тестирования), if a = 1 then * (люблю if(a = 1) {*} ), $ перед переменными, медленную технику и разработка под неё (поэтому даже не пишите: "не учи его, так как он медленный"), комп. игры, ненавижу всё apple -овское (кроме canvas)

**Ещё:** немного знаю англ. и уже могу читать документации на нём

p.p.s. пишите по делу, на всякие: тебе ещё рано, учи русский язык, для тебя это слишком сложно и т.д. буду жаловаться.

Нужен ясный ответ: python или java, и почему.

UD1: То есть все поводы на стороне java. А про phyton поводы есть? Неужели именно java почти идеальный проход для большого старта?
UD2: Решено - java.

Comment: "к 14 знать минимум 7 яп" открою для вас большую истину - надо учиться программированию, а не учить синтаксис 7и языков.

хорошо владею JS (на изучение ушло 1.5 мес. ), спорим, что не хорошо? :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope ну я и имею ввиду уметь писать на 7 языках. Или я в чём-то не прав?
насчёт JS: но тут надо понимать, что именно означает 'хорошо'. По моим представлениям 'хорошо' означает не знания всех функций, а знание лишь около 100 + умение пользоваться поиском. Возможно вы имеете ввиду знание всех штучек без исключения. Чтож, по моему это уже не хорошо, и не даже отлично, а профессионально. Но такого эффекта я добиться не пытаюсь и он мне не нужен. Пока мне моих знаний в большинстве случаев хватает.
Впрочем, можно и поспорить, насчёт хорошо ли я знаю JS или нет.

Comment: >хорошо владею JS (на изучение ушло 1.5 мес. ), спорим, что не хорошо? :)

полностью согласен с @AlexWindHope, полгода назад перешёл на JS после 2-х лет C# и чуть ли не постоянно "нахожу" в нём(js) что-то новое

Comment: "'хорошо' означает не знания всех функций, а знание лишь около 100 + умение пользоваться поиском", спорить не имеет смысла, вы все сами показали этим предложением.

"Пока мне моих знаний в большинстве случаев хватает" это потому-что вы пишете HelloWorld'ы :)

Comment: Я просто оставлю это здесь: [http://habrahabr.ru/post/84311/](http://habrahabr.ru/post/84311/)

:3

Comment: Чёрт, ошибся только с `Number.MIN_VALUE > 0`

от себя добавлю: [Another JavaScript quiz](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/another-javascript-quiz/)

и уже классика [WAT](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: Я вот, помнится, ляпнул один раз, что хорошо знаю `C++` :)

Comment: Лучше к 14ти годам уметь писать хороший код на 2х языках, чем знать синтакис 7ми. Я тоже в 14 "знал" 6 языков )

Comment: @Spectre небольшой оффтоп. Вам помоему понравилось решение 

    var d = dig%10;
    switch(true) {
      case (d == 1): ender = 'ие'; break;
      case ((d >= 2) && (d <= 9)): ender = 'ий'; break;
      //...
    }

Так вот (**warning** - так не стоит делать):

      var d = d % 10, ender;
      d===1?ender='ие':d>=2&&d<=9?ender='ий':ender='default'; // :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope вот никак немогу согласиться с этим. Сейчас я уже дошёл до онлайн-рисовалки (мощной кстати-говоря). Моих знаний мне пока хватает, за исключением пару/тройку случаев. За исключением конечно canvas -а, который я уже изучаю углублённо

Comment: @AlexWindHope, не понял вашей мысли, не стоит делать подобный `switch` или многократновложеный if expression? и почему?

>этого странного switch(true)

хоть и странный(что по определению крайне субъективно), но вполне применим для некоторых ситуаций

>цель была вместить такой switch в 1 не особо длинную строку 

если честно, цель простая, вот если бы у этого свитча был десяток другой кейсов...

Comment: Fuck yeah, я JS гуру :) еще хотел бы добавить, что typeof null не всегда object, вернее, в браузерной среде, это так, но, например v8, имеет флаг, включив который, null считается отдельным типом данных, т.е. typeof null === 'null'.

Если много кейсов - продолжайте строку, просто с должным форматированием. Я таким образом сжимал некоторый парсеры и шаблонизаторы, switch(true), ИМХО, неудобен в абсолютно любом случае.

Comment: Дык эта. Питон и жаба сразу! А для развлечения www.jython.org

Comment: Насчёт закрытия: что значит слишком спорно? В этом мире всё слишком спорно. Но это повод, чтобы продолжать конструктивные дискурии, но ни как не повод закрывать их. Думаю, пока здесь держиться просто конструктивная дискурия, вопрос можно держать открытым. Ещё есть шанс прийти к чему-то общему. Предлагаю обратно открыть вопрос!

Comment: Ага, уже давно не было интересных дискурий.

Comment: @alexz ну как бы это слово обозначает болтовню на тему кто прав. Я так это понимаю )

Comment: Да было где-то ещё у покойного Дейкстры, что без знания естественного языка хорошего программиста быть не может. Правда назвать статью не смогу (ищите и обрящете). Так что знание русского гораздо важнее знания питона или джавы. (У Дейкстры были два условия: хорошее владение естественным языком и умение мыслить математически. Где-то так)

Comment: Да было где-то ещё у покойного Дейкстры, что без знания естественного языка хорошего программиста быть не может. Правда назвать статью не смогу (ищите -- и обрящете). Так что знание русского гораздо важнее знания питона или джавы. (У Дейкстры были два условия: хорошее владение естественным языком и умение мыслить математически. Где-то так)

Comment: Конечно Java. Язык Phyton даже не существует.

Comment: Скажите, а dpetruk — это не вы ли?

Comment: @NickVolynkin мне даже админы по этому поводу писали. Кратко говоря: я создал dpetruk, когда не мог войти в danpetruk. Потом всё-таки войти сумел, а акк dpetruk успешно забросил. Потом этот dpetruk неожиданным образом ожил. Кто-то каким-то образом вошёл в него, не хотя этого, написал несколько ответов, а потом спросил у админов wtf. Те написали, что проблема была и они её решили. Потом я ради эксперимента попробовал войти в dpetruk - не получилось(. Вот такая история бага

Comment: @danpetruk: так наверное нужно объединить аккаунты теперь.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ты вообще прикалываешься. Я немного покритикую (ну пожалуйста)) ) и выскажу свою точку зрения.

> Мне сейчас 11 лет и у меня задача - к 14 знать минимум 7 яп

А зачем? Понятное дело, что очевидным ответом будет "для развития и возможности выбрать, чем в дальнейшем более конкретно заниматься будешь". Но это нереально - за 3 года выучить 7 ЯП (в ЯП я не включаю языки разметки) до уровня, достаточного для использования в разработки. Лучше выбрать 2-3 языка и дополнительно штудировать английский язык - он очень полезен в карьере разработчика.

> Я сейчас уже достаточно хорошо владею JS (на изучение ушло 1.5 мес. )

За полтора месяца этот язык не изучить, анимацию вообще в расчёт можно не брать. Что бы действительно считать себя js-разработчиком, необходимо по крайней мере знать и уметь ,использовать кроме стандартного набора функций, ajax, json, а так же библиотеку jQuery (минимум), и желательно Ext JS, которая используется для разработки RIA.

> Не люблю: pascal, среды разработки (но не средства тестирования), if a = 1 then * (люблю if(a = 1) {*} ), $ перед переменными

Я сам не любитель паскаля и дельфи, но паскаль, например, учит писать правильно и направляет мозги в нужное русло (в школьные годы). Насчёт сред разработки ты вообще неправ, т.к. никто в промышленной разработке npp и прочие простенькие редакторы не использует. Хотя, возможно, под средой разработки ты позразумеваешь зло под названием Adobe Dreamweaver. И если ты собираешься писать на Java, то придётся знакомиться с NetBeans, Eclipse или IntelliJ Idea. Насчёт бакса перед перемеными, то вся эта мода пошла с sh/bash, затем Perl и наконец PHP. ТАк что не хочешь - не пиши на них)) И если тебе не нравится форматирование кода без применения () и {}, то Python тебе не очень понравится.

Ну а теперь по теме - Python и Java языки разной направленности. Оба предельно понятные и довольно лаконичные (в отличии от PHP с его костылями). Python, в основном - язык для веб-разработки и системного программирования, как замена Perl. Java - по сути тоже применима для этого, но логичнее её использовать для разработки проектов корпоративного уровня (так называемая Java EE).

Ну и напоследок - обрати внимание на сайты работы (и русские и забугорные) и посмотри на востребованность тех или иных ЯП. И учти, что многие ЯП имеют свою целевую категорию разработки.

Сам я прошёл по следующему пути: Веб(без программирования на серверной стороне - HTML, CSS, JS) -> PHP -> Java SE -> Java EE. И последнюю, на мой взгляд, можно считать конечной точкой для разработчика (Веб и интерпрайз).

Comment: нет, я имел ввиду не Dreamweaver, а как рас ecslipe. Просто я когда-то попытался выучить java по книге "программирование под android", и там меня eclipse меня взбесил. Правда я не побывал другие среды. Может они и удобные... Но для начала хочу попробовать без них, а уже потом...
Насчёт 7 яп, вы меня окончательно переубедили. Для начало отметка 2-3, а потом уж посмотрим.

"но паскаль, например, учит писать правильно и направляет мозги в нужное русло (в школьные годы). " А чем JS в этом плох? Он меня вроде бы уже направил...

Comment: Понимаешь, я не сравнивал JS и паскаль. JS в приницпе хорош для изучения программирования, не спорю. Паскаль просто изучается в школах в отличии от JS. К Eclipse сложно привыкнуть сразу, но со временем начинаешь понимать все его прелести. Для андроида (и явы в целом) можно попробовать Idea. Кстати, если ты хочешь программировать на платформе Android, то рекомендую начать с Java, т.к. на андроиде именно она, только под JVM Dalvik.

З.ы.: мне кажется, или я пишу от твоего имени?

Comment: Ну ладно, всё равно в конце концов родители заставляют ходить на кружок про pascal. 
Насчёт среды - когда почувствую необходимость - перепробую разные варианты. Но пока начну без неё.
Насчёт дроида - тут я не согласен, что только java. Да, главная она, но есть интерпретаторы (я ничего не перепутал?) JS и python для него. Так что если мне срочно понадобиться сделать app для android, то можно и на js его написать. А так, этим я хочу потом заняться.

Comment: По сути, насколько я знаю, то, что ты напишешь на Js или Python, будет скомпилировано в java-классы и выполнено на jvm, так что лучше изначально писать на Java.

Comment: Ну не знаю. Всё равно потеря скорости. Так что то, что лучше писать на java - это бесспорно. Вот только java надо ещё выучить. Пожалуй я и буду её перевей учить.

Comment: Вброшу тезис. А нужна ли скорость? Когда основное время типичный ведройный софт занимается UI, а тот ограничен скоростью тыканья пользователем по экрану и разница — за 1ms или 10ms будет обработано нажатие на кнопку, в общем-то, никакой роли не играет.

BTW, оффтопиком, поправлю.

> Насчёт бакса перед перемеными, то вся эта мода пошла с sh/bash

На самом деле, сигилы пошли, насколько я знаю, с BASIC. В ряде его диалектов `$` использовался для обозначения строкового типа. И, немного, MUMPS, где `^` использовали для глобальных переменных. В шелле (началось с Mashey shell) оно было уже позднее.

Comment: @drdaeman Только в basic'е доллар ставился сзади строковой переменной. А разработчики sh вероятно заимствовали это из какого-нибудь макропроцессора.

Answer (score 9):

Не заморачивайтесь на синтаксисе. Это ерунда, которая не стоит внимания — преобразовать один синтаксис в другой — задача, не считая времени на продумывание синтаксисов, в общем-то, на несколько вечеров. Обращайте внимание не на форму скобочек и отступы, а на семантику языка.

Python, на мой взгляд, будет семантически побогаче Java. Там и генераторы с сопрограммами, и метаклассы, и функции высшего порядка без особых танцев с бубном (и всякий синтаксический сахар под эти возможности, типа декораторов), и еще куча всего. Правда, и своих бед хватает.

Поэтому я бы предложил *сначала* Java (до определенного порога, а то в мире ее библиотек можно годами копаться), потом Python. Общие концепции (итераторы, например) будут потом полезны и в Python. Зато, выбрав Java первым не придется сильно плеваться, когда придется писать десяток строк кода вместо какого-нибудь коротенького генераторного выражения.

А потом, интереса ради, можно посмотреть на Scala'у, например.

Comment: раз уж на то пошло: правда ли, что scala лишь для больших любителей java? Не знаете?

Comment: Ну-у, даже не знаю что и сказать.

С одной стороны, оно живет на Java-как-платформе. Т.е. большая часть библиотек и фреймворков будет от Java. Так что Scala явно для тех, кому нравится экосистема Java как таковая.

Но, с другой стороны, как язык, она выглядит куда ближе к ML'ям (ее одно время любили сравнивать с Haskell), чем Java. И все это сдобрено концепцией актеров, местами явно навеянной Erlang'ом.

Серьезно, я правда, Scala не щупал — только думал посмотреть (но все руки не доходили дальше, по сути, helloworld'ов), так что за особую правдивость не поручаюсь.

Comment: Сначала я подумал, что про синтаксис вы правы и то, что особой разницы нет. Но потом я вспомнил про читаемость кода. Сверху, я уже написал, что люблю open source, а значит читаемость кода мне важна. На мой взгляд у JS самый читаемый синтаксис. Поэтому я ищу яп, с синтаксисом, похожим на него.
If(){}, переменная без $ делают код понятным. А вот смотрю на php, pascal - да это тихий ужас. Если в коде >100 строчек и нету коментов, то заблудиться легко. 
Так что я ищю читаемый, объектный, кроссплатформенный, мощный яп

Comment: читаемость кода - понятие субъективное, поэтому одним обычные и фигурные скобки кажутся отличным качеством читаемости, другим наоборот нравятся только отступы, с другой стороны причина нечитаемости кода не язык, а его пользователь

Comment: Прежде всего я надеюсь, чтоб код был читаем для меня. А что такое 'читаемость' кода для меня - вы уже наверно поняли )

Comment: Читаемость кода — да, важный фактор, которым нельзя пренебрегать. 

Но в меру — если проблемы с чтением начинаются с сигила у имени переменной или формы блоков, не давая читать если вместо `{ ... }` оказывается индентация или `begin ... end` — дело плохо. Каждый, конечно, сам себе хозяин, но лично я бы советовал тут перебороть собственное сознание, абстрагироваться от формы и научиться читать содержание.

![http://i.imgur.com/9mulv.png][1]

(Картинка приукрашает дело только в вопросе префиксной/инфиксной нотации — вот это уже настоящий вопрос читаемости.)

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/9mulv.png

Comment: Не согласен с этой картинкой. В мою голову хорошо впиваются и () и {}.
Насчёт переучения: можно конечно заставить себя писать только код, который со start и end. Но это будет слишком грубо по отношению к себе. Ладно, пока поживу на {} и (), а потом помотрить...

Answer (score 5):

Для начала - в корне не согласен с "Выучив Яву легче учить другие языки", знаю любой язык программирования намного проще изучать другой, на мой взгляд, да и по моему личному опыту, польза от Java, в вопросе изучения других языков, точно такая-же, как от любого другого.

Теперь по сабжу - не являюсь фанатом ни первого языка, ни второго, но, тем не менее - склоняюсь к Python. Объяснение - намного больше шансов, в короткие сроки, освоить язык и приступить к разработке. Для того, что-бы, на Java, не писать плохой код - должно пройти довольно много времени, а для того, что-бы писать хороший и вовсе - годы ( это не учитывая моментов справедливых для любого ЯП, я имею введу именно специфику хорошего Java кода ).

А вообще, пускай и не имеет отношения к вашему вопросу - не учите язык ради языка, просто знать синтаксис N языка != быть программистом на N языке. Но, если вам, на данном этапе, интересует именно это, то я бы посоветовал изучать старый добрый С.

PS: 'Моих знаний мне пока хватает, за исключением пару/тройку случаев', все мы так, когда-то думали, у меня к вам вопрос - если вы настолько одаренный программист и у вас все и так получается - зачем вы спрашиваете что учить дальше? Вы, скорее всего, знаете намного лучше.

Comment: 'PS: 'Моих знаний мне пока хватает, за исключением пару/тройку случаев', все мы так, когда-то думали, у меня к вам вопрос - если вы настолько одаренный программист и у вас все и так получается - зачем вы спрашиваете что учить дальше? Вы, скорее всего, знаете намного лучше.' так это же для определённого случая, да ещё вдобавок ПОКА. 
Да и не так много строчек кода я написал - около 500 строчек кода. Ну и соотношение - 3/500. Это точно не супер программист, тем более
что на эти 500 ушло где-то 1.5 месяца.

Comment: > Да и не так много строчек кода я написал - около 500 строчек кода

Тогда может вам все же остаться пока в русле JS? Пока не накопится... эммм... больше строчек.

Comment: @Nofate JS ну я планирую дописать свою рисовалку до конца, а в ней и все 50 000 могут набраться :)

Comment: @danpetruk, вот вам и фронт работ на ближайшие полгода )

Comment: @Nofate полгода? Вы думаете? Я на три года расчитывал )

Answer (score 2):

Я бы начинал с Java и вот почему.
Синтаксис Java имеет очень много общего с С++, PHP и другими языками программирования. Также реализация ООП в Яве имеет много общего с другими языками программирования. Выучив Яву легче учить другие языки.

Answer (score 0):

Java.

Почему:

1. Простота (установка среды разработки не требуется. Только распаковать архив).
2. Легкая в обучении.
3. Подходит и для разработки ПО и для Web-development.
4. Идет на все платформы (Android, Linux, Windows...).
5. "Нету $"
6. EXE (JAR) - файл не занимает много места (при наличии 5 - 7 классов 10 - 80 Кб.)
7. Можно установить МНОГО других библиотек.

Эпилог. Если вы выбрали java вот ссылка на среду: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/.
Ваш выбор.

Comment: Java легкая в обучении? Да вы что?

Comment: 1. Без среды разработки разрабатывать на яве - чистой воды извращение (если проект много больше hello-world и юзает сторонние библиотеки).
2. SE - да (питон, кстати, тоже простой), EE - нет
6. Если используются библиотеки (хотя бы Spring), то софтина неслабо так разрастается. Да и что такое "5-7 классов"??
ИМХО, эклипс - не для новичков. Лучше попробовать NetBeans для начала.

Comment: Думаю он имел ввиду простата - легко начать.

Comment: Да. Такой смысл

Comment: @dpetruk Питон проще джавы в освоении (в т.ч. и за счёт REPL -- read-evalution-print-loop и средств типа dir(), `.__doc__` и т.д.).

А вот фраза "Думаю он имел ввиду под словом простата - легко начать" -- это что-то из рекламы средств от простатита. "Простота" пишется с двумя "о".